# Proxying HTTP requests in Angular 7

Tags: node.js, angular

Previously I was using "proxy.conf.json" to proxy http requests in Angular which was working fine. Now I want to make the proxy urls dynamic, for which I have created a "proxy.conf.js" as mentioned in the Angular Wiki (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md) and added the following:

```
    const PROXY_CONFIG = [
      {
        context: [
          "/api/*"
        ],
        target: "https://example.com/",
        logLevel: "debug",
        secure: false,
        changeOrigin: true
      },
      {
        context: [
          "/login/*"
        ],
        target: "https://example1.com/",
        logLevel: "debug",
        secure: false,
        changeOrigin: true
      }
  ]
  module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

And in the "package.json", I have added the following:

```
"start-dev": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.js",
```

But when I run this script "npm run start-dev", it does not read from the "proxy.conf.js" file although it says "Proxy created".

```
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
10% building 3/3 modules 0 active[HPM] Proxy created: [ '/login/*' ]  ->  https://example1.com/
```

Instead of making http request to "https://example.com/", the url is still pointing to "http://localhost:4200/"

[image]

Could someone please let me know if there is anything I'm missing out here.

Comment: It will still point to localhost but in console you should notice what proxy is used

Comment: I guess its not like that. When I use proxy.conf.json file I could see the proxy url in the console but not when I use proxy.conf.js file.

Comment: It's a proxy. So the browser doesn't know anything about it: it sends its AJAX requests to localhost:4200, and the dev server forwards the request to example.com, and sends the response it gets to the browser.

Comment: The context `/login/* `does not match the request `/login`

Comment: I understand that in console I won't see the proxy url, but in any case it gives 404 error where as it works fine if I use the proxy.conf.json file. May be I am missing out on some stupid configurations.

Comment: @eckes You are absolutely correct. In the json file I used to add the paths like "/login/*" but did not realise in JS the context, ithas to be "/login". After changing the path it's working fine. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Oh thanks, added it as an answer as well. @Ansuman

Comment: Accepted.... :)

Comment: @eckes Quick question, somewhat related. I am passing 
"proxyConfig": "proxy.conf.js:env". How do I capture this env value in proxy.conf.js?

Comment: @Ansuman not sure, maybe it works the same as the webpack env injection? module.export = (env = {}) => { …`

Comment: Anyway I have done some workarounds and it's working now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Proxy configuration the context pattern is `/login/*` however the actual request according to your console output is simply `/login` with no trailing component.

Therefore this proxy rule das not match and the dev server has no local resource for this and therefore answers with a 404.

You can either change the context or add a second entry for `/login`.